# Old School Feel text appearing one letter at a time issue

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer

Well, as the title says I'm trying to create an old school type app. I meant the computer programming green on black, with the text (of the programming) (like in terminal/windows program input) and I'm trying to get my string be shown on screen one letter at a time. 
So I decided to try for an example, here is my code, any advice would be awesome! :)

```
    instructionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];
    instructionsString = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, ...";

  for (int i = 1 ; i <= [instructionsString length]; i++) {
    [instructionsArray addObject:@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:[instructionsString characterAtIndex:i]]];
}
```

So basically I had this example string; instructionsString (which is just an NSString) and this MutableArray. I thought that it would be simplest to turn the string into characters into an array, and then with an NSTimer, display each item of the array, any simpler and better methods would appreciated!

thanks

EDIT: Thank you Hypercube I changed my code to:

```
            [Instructions.text stringByAppendingString:[remainingBuffer subStringWithRange: NSmakeRange(1, remainingBuffer.length - 1)]];
```

However, I still get this error and warning:
No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'subStringWithRange'
and a warning 'NSmakeRange' is invalid for C99

Any help would be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Comment: Your macro should be named NSMakeRange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is oddly specific, because like a week ago I wrote something to visually emulate a dot matrix printer, which faces the same problem.

I'd forget the array of characters altogether, since that's what a string is anyway, and just keep an `NSString remainingBuffer` object.  Ever time the NSTimer says it's time to print a character, if the buffer isn't empty, read the first character from it, print the character, and remove the first character from the buffer like this:

```
remainingBuffer = [remainingBuffer subStringWithRange: NSmakeRange(1, remainingBuffer.length - 1)];
```

Which, if `NSString` is designed correctly, shouldn't allocate any new data for the text, but just return an NSString whose internal pointer to its array of characters is one character length greater than the old string.

Whenever you need to tell your console to print something, just append to the `remainingBuffer`

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much, however, when I try to input this... (having properly allocated the NSString remainingBuffer of course)
I get the error:
No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'subStringWithRange'
and a warning 'NSmakeRange' is invalid for C99
with the code: 

                [Instructions.text stringByAppendingString:[remainingBuffer subStringWithRange: NSmakeRange(1, remainingBuffer.length - 1)]];
  
Did I do something wrong? :P I just made my string = remaining buffer, then inputer your string.

Comment: I might have gotten the capitalization wrong. It could very easily be `substringWithRange:` and `NSMakeRange`.  You'll have to check the docs - I'm working off memory because I'm answering from my phone

Comment: EDIT: My fault, error was I forgot about 1/2 the code. it works but it just puts all the text in at one :/ but thank you !